Dynamic Response Handling for Multi-Tenant APIs

I am developing logic to handle REST API responses for different tenants (e.g., tenants A, B, and C) using a unified API approach. Each tenant has a specific response format based on a general response. For example, Tenant A will return General, and Tenant B will return General, and I plan to apply this approach to other APIs as well.

I intend to manage these responses within a manager class and utilize a factory method to ensure that the appropriate function from the relevant manager is called for each tenant. However, I am concerned that as the number of tenants increases, the interface might become overloaded with functions, making it challenging to manage.

Additionally, if there are some APIs might affect only specific tenants (e.g., Tenant A), and if I include these in the general interface, all inherited interfaces for other tenants would need to accommodate these new methods, which could lead to complications.



Here's my current flow

The MetaFactory class is used to determine which MetaManager should be called based on the tenant's subdomain:

   class MetaFactory( 
    private val defaultMetaManager: DefaultMetaManager, 
    private val tenantAMetaManager: TenantAMetaManager, 
    private val tenantBMetaManager: TenantBMetaManager, 
   ) { 
     fun getMetaManager(subdomain: Subdomain): MetaManager {   
      return when (subdomain) {     
        TenantA -> TenantAMetaManager     
        TenantB -> TenantBMetaManager     
        else -> defaultMetaManager   
      } 
     } 
   }


The MetaManager interface defines all required functions that a controller can call, including both general and tenant-specific responses:

  interface MetaManager {
    // All tenant requires these responses
    fun getDefaultResponse1() : GeneralResponse1<Meta> // api 1 call to
    fun getDefaultResponse2() : GeneralResponse2<Meta> // api 2 call to

    // Specific responses for tenant A
    fun getTenantAResponse1() : GeneralResponse1<Meta> // a specific api from tenant A call to
    fun getTenantAResponse2() : GeneralResponse2<Meta> // a specific api from tenant A call to

    // Specific responses for tenant B
    fun getTenantBResponse1() : GeneralResponse2<Meta> // a specific api from tenant B call to
  }


Define response data classes with a Meta interface to handle specific responses:

data class GeneralResponse1<E: Meta?(
  val id: UUID,
  val name: String
  val meta: E?
)

data class TenantAResponse1(
  val score: Int?
): Meta


Implement the MetaManager interface for each tenant, defining how each function returns specific responses:

  class TenantAMetaManager(): MetaManager() {
    override fun getDefaultResponse1() : GeneralResponse1<Meta> // todo
    override fun getDefaultResponse2() : GeneralResponse2<Meta> // todo

    override fun getTenantAResponse1() : GeneralResponse1<Meta> // todo
    override fun getTenantAResponse2() : GeneralResponse2<Meta> {
      val score = getScore() // random function to resolve the score
      val meta = TenantAResponse1(
       score = score
      )
      return GeneralResponse2(meta)
    }

    override fun getTenantBResponse1() : GeneralResponse2<Meta> // todo
  }


The controller then can determine which response to return by checking the subdomain and using the factory method.

@Get("/") 
fun A (request: Request, subdomain: Subdomain): GeneralResponse1<Meta> {
   return metaFactory(subdomain).getMetaManager()
}

There are some concerns as I said:

Inconvenience: The current design requires defining a comprehensive interface with many functions, which can become cumbersome as the number of tenants grows.
Specific APIs: When new APIs are introduced that affect only certain tenants, they need to be added to the general interface, which may result in unnecessary complexity for other tenants.


I don't think methods like getTenantAResponse1 that are specific to a type of tenant be present on the MetaManager, instead you can/should define them in TenantAMetaManager.
